# Class'objects deleted randomly

Tags: ruby, oop

I have a ruby class named `Table`, and I'm iterating over a csv file to create an object of this class for every row if this row's first element hasn't been seen yet.

Here is the code:

```
require 'csv'
class Table
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @columns = {}
  end
end

csv_tables = File.read("db_apm.csv")
csv_tables = CSV.parse(csv_tables, :headers => true)
csv_tables.each_with_index do |row, index|
  # Check if object with the name present at row[0] has already been created 
  if ObjectSpace.each_object(Table).find { |object| object.instance_variable_get(:@name) == row[0] }.nil?
    table = Table.new(row[0])
    p row[0]
  end
  p ObjectSpace.each_object(Table).to_a.count
end
p "Final count"
p ObjectSpace.each_object(Table).to_a.count
```

The csv file never changes, but I'm seeing some weird results:

1. First, the count before the end of the each loop restarts at 0 during the same run of the script (I can see 1, 2, 3, ... 50, 1 , 2 , 3 ).
2. Also, the final count changes between each run of the script. I sometimes get 17, or I can get 204 etc, it seems very random.

I don't understand why this is happening since the file isn't changing, and the code is pretty straightforward.

Here is a small extract of the file:

```
LOG_RECHERCHE
LOG_RECHERCHE
LOG_RECHERCHE
LOG_RECHERCHE
LOG_RECHERCHE
INTERVENTION
INTERVENTION
INTERVENTION
INTERVENTION
INTERVENTION
INTERVENTION
INTERVENTION
INTERVENTION
INTERVENTION
INTERVENTION
INTERVENTION
INTERVENTION
SUIVI_SCRIPT_SQL
SUIVI_SCRIPT_SQL
SUIVI_SCRIPT_SQL
SUIVI_SCRIPT_SQL
VUE_COMPILE_RENCONTRE
VUE_COMPILE_RENCONTRE
VUE_COMPILE_RENCONTRE
VUE_COMPILE_RENCONTRE
VUE_COMPILE_RENCONTRE
VUE_COMPILE_RENCONTRE
```

For this, the final count should be 4. I'm not sure the issue will occur with a small part of the file (the final count should be about 200 with the whole file).

Is ruby deleting objects for some reasons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a memory management mechanizm called [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)).

In Ruby it is implemented in [GC module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/GC.html).

What it does, is removing objects, which are no longer used/referenced, to optimize memory usage.

Since you are not storing your created objects of `Table` class anywhere, GC treats them as garbage, and collects.

You can inspect the `ObjectSpace` by [`disable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/GC.html#method-c-disable)'ing garbage collection before the loop, for example.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I knew about GC, but what surprised me is that it didn't removed the same number of objects for each run